# How to stop slider when embedded youtube video is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use a slider that I have managed to stop on mouseover. The slide also have an embedded youtube video, and Im trying to stop and resume the slider when someone clicks the video.

Codepen with live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjKOGY

How do I stop the slider when video plays?

Embdeeded the video with an Id and enabled Js. I then call this code:

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
  height: '315',
  width: '560',
  videoId: 'Vhh_GeBPOhs',
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
}
var VSliderHome = true;
var myPlayerState;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    VSliderHome = false;
    }
    myPlayerState = event.data;
  }
if (myPlayerState == 1){
VSliderHome = true;
}
```

slidescript:

```
    var VSliderHome = true;
$("#SliderHome").hover(function() {
VSliderHome = false;
}, function() {
   VSliderHome = true;
});

function autoplaySlider(length) {
    if (VSliderHome) {
        if (visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
        nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
        visibleSlidePosition += 1;
    } else {
        prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
        visibleSlidePosition = 0;
    }
    updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
    updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<slider.body>
<section class="cd-hero">
<ul id="SliderHome" class="cd-hero-slider autoplay">
    <li class="selected">
        <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
            <img src="http://codyhouse.co/demo/hero-slider/assets/tech-2.jpg" alt="tech 2">
        </div>
        <!-- .cd-half-width.cd-img-container -->
        <div class="cd-half-width">
            <div class="textcont-right">
                <h2>Slide title here</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In consequatur cumque natus!</p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">Start</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .cd-half-width -->
    </li>
    <li style="background-image: url()">
        <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
            <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vhh_GeBPOhs?enablejsapi" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <!-- .cd-half-width.cd-img-container -->
        <div class="cd-half-width">
            <div class="textcont-right">
                <h2>text</h2>
                <p> elit. In consequatur cumque natus!</p>
                <a href="#" class="cd-btn">button</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .cd-half-width -->
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="cd-slider-nav">
    <nav>
        <span class="cd-marker item-1"></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><a href="#0"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#0"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

</section>
</body>
```

Comment: add a class above your youtube iframe and on its click event you can manage to stop the slide just like you did on mousehover.

Comment: Hi! I placed the iframe in a new container and replicated the hover code and replaced the class and .hover to .click but it didn't work. And How would the slider resume after the video plays out? thanks though!

Comment: It might be that your class event is not getting triggered. There is another alternative though, check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624904/youtube-embeded-action-when-video-ends

Comment: The tubeplayer plugin looks promising. will give it a go!